# Theos Make Issues

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I've been following this tutorial:
http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-building-and-deployment/

to get an application started by the name of foobar. But when I type 'make', I get...

```
19:33:14-~/code/theos/foobar$ make
Making all for application foobar...
 Compiling main.m...
 Compiling foobarApplication.mm...
 Compiling RootViewController.mm...
 Linking application foobar...
ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [obj/foobar] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-application-all_] Error 2
make: *** [foobar.all.application.variables] Error 2
```

Because I'm using theos instead xcode (although 4.5 is installed, with version 6.0 SDK), changing build settings doesn't help.

FYI I'm developing for iphone iOS 4.3.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently a known issue in theos, you should put the following at the top of your makefile if you only have access to Xcode 4.5 with the iOS6 SDK:

```
ARCHS = armv7
```

if you have access to older SDKs, the following will allow you to compile for armv6 successfully:

```
TARGET = iphone:sdkversion
```

where sdkversion is a numerical string of the form "4.0" etc, so if you want to use the 5.1 SDK (which is the latest that will allow you to create armv6 objects), put the following at the top of your makefile:

```
TARGET = iphone:5.1
```

Comment: thanks @jonsca, I guess I need to familiarize myself with formatting here on SO, didn't know indents created code blocks

Comment: No problem at all!  When you're in the editor, there's an orange question mark above and to the right of the textbox which has some other hints, too.